# Element animates and keeps returning after completion

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an element which is a login button, it fades in, then i apply some JavaScript to change the animation to a fade out when it is clicked. But once the fade out is complete the element appears again even though i added a `hidden` class to the element so it should remain hidden.

This is how i have it setup:

```js
const login = document.getElementById('login');
login.addEventListener('animationend', onComplete);

function onComplete(event) {
  if (event.animationName == "anim-show") {
    login.addEventListener('click', onClick);
  } else if (event == "anim-hide") {
    login.classList.add("hidden");
  }
}

function onClick() {
  login.style.animationName = "anim-hide";
  login.removeEventListener('click', onClick);
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#login {
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 10px;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #466995;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  animation: anim-show .5s ease;
  user-select: none;
}

@keyframes anim-show {
  from {
    margin-bottom: 25%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-hide {
  from {
    margin-top: 0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 25%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="login">Login To Website</div>
```

Once the `anim-hide` animation completes, the `hidden` class is applied so it should remain hidden. Yet the element still appears on the page.
I would have thought it would at least remain with an opacity of 0 but apparently that isn't happening and i do not know why.

Comment: Please also include the relevant HTML.

Comment: I've add the div element though its only one line, had to add the styling for the element too which i had stripped out to keep it simple to read.

Comment: Its a typo: `else if (event == "anim-hide") {` should be `else if (event.animationName == "anim-hide") {`

Comment: @imvain2 ohh thank you! Thats weird chrome console isn't reporting that error.

Comment: @WDUK that is because technically there is no "error" for it to report. The browser tries to evaluate `event == "anim-hide"` and it will simply return false every time. The event variable exists and `== "anim-hide"` is valid markup so there isn't an error to report.

Comment: JavaScript allows comparing values of different types. So it's not an error to compare an `Event` object to a string. But the comparison will always fail.

Comment: I see, is there anyway for it to give hints since it will always fail i would've been there forever otherwise not realising my logic error.

Comment: @WDUK, I like to just use `console.log`  for debugging. I would have `console.log(event)` to try and figure out what parameter was being passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[with a little effort you could have found this on your own...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

```css
animation-fill-mode : forwards;
```

```js
const login = document.getElementById('login');

login.addEventListener('click', onClick);


function onClick() {
  login.style.animationName = "anim-hide";
  login.removeEventListener('click', onClick);
}
```

```css
#login {
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 10px;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #466995;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  animation: anim-show .5s ease;
  user-select: none;
  
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;  /* just this */
}

@keyframes anim-hide {
  from {
    margin-top: 0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 25%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-show {
  from {
    margin-bottom: 25%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="login">Login To Website</div>
```